# Roles and Deny Precedence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So i have a Ad group on a database which i want to deny from viewing a table but i want give access to one person from AD Account.

I'm not sure if it is possible.
I highly think its not.
but maybe i could be wrong so i am asking. Is it possible for that to happen without removing the username from the ad account?could you provide me with the best solution on how to approach this ?
note i have already created the roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group inherits permissions to all the members that it contains. So NO, you cant do that with AD Group.

You can use database roles but that has to be on individual logins in your case.

Best is to

- Remove that login from AD group and grant indivudual permission or make it part of database role and grant permissions to that role.
- Ask that user to use sql authentication so that the person can view table.

Comment: @kin what would happen if the user was in two groups or was in one and then also had an explicit AD logon? Is least privileged applied? I couldn’t find anything solid on it.